# Old user is still there?

Tags: mariadb

I have found a weird phenomenon on my MariaDB server (version 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1)

I used to have a user XYZ long time ago, and this user probably got deleted sometime. However, I tried to login using this user and I got the following error message:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1275): Server is running in
>   --secure-auth mode, but 'XYZ'@'localhost' has a password in the old format; please change the password to the new format

Just to be sure, I tried to login using a non-existing user. For example, I try to login as NOTEXISTING, just to verify that the error message is indeed different.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'NOTEXISTING'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Now, the question is, where is the old user information stored?

The user does not exist in the mysql database:

```
select * from mysql.user where user = 'XYZ';
```

=> empty result

```
grep -r XYZ /path_to_mysql_database_dir/mysql/
```

=> nothing

I also tried "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" to reload the user table.

Do you have an idea where the user information is stored?

**Update**

After trying various things and even testing on a completely fresh installed system, I come to the conclusion that it must be some kind of bug, so I opened a bug report: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17789 . Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A developer has confirmed that the (in my opinion wrong) error message is intentional behavior, based on a hash of the user table.

https://jira.mariadb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MDEV-17789

Answer (score 0):

The plaintext password is not stored anywhere.

`SELECT user, host, password FROM user` *may* provide something like

```
| pm_demo          | localhost   | FFC3F585           |
| dist             | localhost   | A8900DDB           |
| ronly            | localhost   | 5208517A           |
| spent            | localhost   | 26B08F08           |
| test             | 1.2.3.4     | A40C6DCC           |
```

That "password" is really an encrypted version of the plaintext password.  It is the "old format", which is not very secure.  New passwords look more like

```
*A5280BD3F8C6BCC6537FCC3E113D794DD53534CC
```

There are also other authentication mechanisms.  (I don't know where you are in the evolution of authentication.)

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user = 'xyz'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Host: localhost
                  User: xyz
              Password: *6D800EA40C6DCC75BFF67DAB58D5D49FC5F8E568
           Select_priv: N
           Insert_priv: N
           Update_priv: N
           Delete_priv: N
           Create_priv: N
             Drop_priv: N
           Reload_priv: N
         Shutdown_priv: N
          Process_priv: N
             File_priv: N
            Grant_priv: N
...
          x509_subject: 
         max_questions: 0
           max_updates: 0
       max_connections: 0
  max_user_connections: 0
                plugin: mysql_native_password
 authentication_string: 
      password_expired: N
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


SHOW GRANTS FOR xyz@localhost;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for xyz@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'xyz'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6D800EA40C6DCC75BFF67DAB58D5D49FC5F8E568' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xyz`.* TO 'xyz'@'localhost'                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes, I know all that. But in the `user` table, as I mentioned, there is *no user* with the name "XYZ", so "show grants" as well as "select ... from user" does not return anything. I have verified that the message comes from the plugin mysql_native_password (using "default-authentication-plugin"), which *should* query the user table.

Comment: I come to the conclusion that it must be a bug in MariaDB, since the wrong error message disappears when I change anything at the user table (i.e. removing or adding any user, or changing specific user names). If I do so, I get the normal "access denied" message when I try to login as this non-existing user.

Comment: @DanielMarschall - See `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: I don't want to sound disrespectful, but I did all that, and it is also written in the question